# Position of footnotemark after includegraphics

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning, footnotes

I know a lot of questions have been asked about `footnote`s in `caption`s and others. 
I am currently working on a `beamer` presentation where such mechanism is not always necessary, on the contrary, `\footnotes` might (I insist on the might) be more relevant there.

I tried to add a `\footnote` just after an `\includegraphics` call but the footnote number is placed at the bottom of the picture, which feels kind of weird. I'd prefer the mark to be placed near the top right corner.

It probably is easy to solve, but when searching the internet, I always fall back to the `\footnote` with `\caption` related questions.

Here is an example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}\footnote{A footnote for an image without figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \raisebox{-\dimexpr\height-\baselineskip}{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}\footnote{A footnote for an image without figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer ! Do you know what makes it different between *normal* text and the `\includegraphics` ?

Comment: Your graphic is much higher than normal text. Try `aaa{\Huge A}\footnote{A}` and you will see the same effect.

Comment: So you mean that the default `\footnote` placement is font size independent? Isn't that weird ? I though it would have been placed with respect to the previous text, at some percentage of the height.

Comment: Sure, but the "height" is the font size and a graphic doesn't change this. {\Huge A} does change the fontsize, but after the group the fontsize is smaller again and footnote use this. If you would put the footnote inside the group you would get some different.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explainations.